# In moqui how to restrict for limit languages in drop down?

Tags: moqui

I've implemented an application using Moqui Framework. I am using

```
    <set field="localeStringList" from="[]"/>
    <iterate list="Locale.getAvailableLocales()" entry="lcl"><script>localeStringList.add([locale:lcl.toString(), name:lcl.getDisplayName(ec.user.locale)])</script></iterate>
    <order-map-list list="localeStringList"><order-by field-name="name"/></order-map-list>
```

In this case I can get a full list of languages.How can I get four languages in drop down.For that what I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct option is to use the drop-down.option element instead of drop-down.list-options and have an element for each Locale you want with an explicit key and value.

Another option is to change your data preparations actions to explicitly add the locales you want.

For reusability you could add a service that returns a List with the locale and name like the current data prep could.

You could also define a reusable widget in a widget-templates file, and include it in your form field using the widget-template-include element.

Comment: From where this languages are loading into drop down.

Comment: The code you included in the original question shows this. The 'iterate' tag iterates over the list returned by Locale.getAvailableLocales() and that is why all locales supported by the JVM are included.